# what's the best approach should i adopt for this php problem

Tags: php, mysql

**Note:** This question is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418275/whats-the-best-approach-i-should-adopt-for-this-php-problem)
**hello everybody,**
 
I have a predefind list of 15 keywords and there is mysql table against each keyword. Now what i want to do is that
first i want to check a keyword and then insert it into the relevant table. This process continue agian and again under foreach
loop.
My question is what kind of approach should i used i.e is it with if else statements, like

```
foreach($keyword as $key=>$val)
{
  if($val==='keyword1'
   {
     $query="insert into keyword1_tab values('', $val);
     $rs=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
   }
   else
      if($val==='keyword2')
       {
         $query="insert into keyword2_tab values('', $val);
         $rs=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
       }
     else
       .
       .
       .
       .
       .
      else
       if($val==='keyword15')
       {
       $query="insert into keyword3_tab values('', $val);
       $rs=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
       }
}
```

**Or something else is used for this which can maintain the speed and consistency.**

Comment: No there are 15 tables look at my updated queries thnx for correction

Comment: Why not have just one table and add a "keyword" field to it?

Comment: actually each keyword have its name and id first i want to count how many times the keyword encounter save this no to one table and insert the name and id to the relevant keyword

Comment: you should store all keywords in one table of many-to-many relation kind. and count your keywords using SQL query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tables = array('keyword1' => 'keyword1_tab', 'keyword2' => 'keyword2_tab' ...);

foreach($keyword as $key=>$val)
{
    if (isset($tables[$val]))
    {
        $query="insert into `".$tables[$val]."` values('', '".$val."')";
        $rs = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: what if i want to find the count of particular keyword i.e foreach loop count keyword1 for 5 time insert it to the table then how 
i know the count of keyword1 should i place i variable for each keyword and when this keyword is match the variable is increamented.

Comment: `$keyword_counts = array_count_values($keyword); foreach($keyword_counts as $key => $key_count) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

## You should use just one table. Period.

That's the only proper way.
Using separate tables for the same matter is against all rules.
You need to learn basics of relational databases design and make your database schema fit into these basic rules.

I see not much sense in these inserts though. What are you doing in general? What is purpose of all that inserts?

Comment: the basic idea is that there are 15 keywords each with its name and category i want to count how many times a keyword is encounter save the no in one table and save the name in other table of that keyword so that in future when i match these keywords with new list of keywords so first it will match the count no(%) and then look for the name of keyword in another table.

Comment: @souce you have to ask another question describing all that keyword stuff and you will get complete and full answers. in short, you shouldn't save number of keywords, this number should be counted by SQL query, from ONE table

Comment: sir send me a test mail at this email `iphoned99@gmail.com` i will send you the whole problem.

Comment: @souce you have to post it in the form of the question, so, the community will be able to help you. A community is always better than just one person.

Answer (score 0):

You could always make it prettier using a switch case:

```
foreach($keywords as $key=>$val){
    $query = "";
    switch($val){
        case "keyword1":
            $query = "YOUR_QUERY_HERE";
        break;
        case "keyword2":
            $query = "YOUR_QUERY_HERE";
        break;
    }
    if(query != ""){
        $rs = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the purpose of `$query = "";`

Comment: @source code Making sure the variable is always initialized, I guess. The `if ($query != "")` will raise an error if the PHP config is set to a low threshold.

Comment: @jensgram `if isset($query) {...}`

Comment: @biakaveron Yes, that's another possibility, but it will not guard againt the `$query` variable being (inadvertently) set earlier in the code. It's a matter of taste, though.